# Automation error - Exception occured in addin

Tags: excel, vba, excel-addins

We have a macro addin in our company that I cannot run on one computer (on another computers it runs correctly) with **Automation error Exception occured.** Can you please tell me where is the mistake ?

```
Sub importFromActiveSheet()
    If ActiveSheet Is currDoc Then
        MsgBox "You cannot import data from current document" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Please select other file", vbCritical, "Wrong source data file"
        Exit Sub
    End If 
    ....

Property Get currDoc() As Worksheet         'returns current document worksheet in tool
    Set currDoc = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
End Property
```

The error will pop up at the sentence :

```
    Set currDoc = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
```

After this the excel will fall down.

[image: Error]

Can you help me please ?

Comment: In VBE, open Tools - References and look for errors in the top of the list. If you find any errors there, then you have probably found your problem.

Comment: Do you get any error with something like `If activesheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)`?

Comment: I assume it's not *actually* an add-in (xlam) file since the active sheet would never be part of an add-in?

Answer (score 0):

I had VBA code that ran an query and put the result into an array. (Originally there were no userforms.)

This would would work in the first instance after creating the spreadsheet, but upon closing and reopening this would cause the Automation error, Exception occurred error message to appear.

Then discovered that if I reopened the spreadsheet and made a change to the spreadsheet (populating a cell etc.), then ran the query, that it would work.

I tried populating a cell from the code containing the query, but this did not work.

Here's my solution / workaround:

I created a userform with a textbox (containing a random value) and a button.
The visibility of the textbox was set to false.
Upon clicking the button, the value contained within the textbox would populate a cell  on the spreadsheet, close the userform, and then trigger the VBA code for the query.

This is not an elegant solution but it seems to have solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue and tried all the suggestions in the posts about this. In the end what worked for me was doing one Thisworkbook.save before launching any userform. This is the vba code I use to launch userforms from a button now.

```
Public SaveOnce as Boolean

Sub Add_Sales_Entry_Launch()

    If AlreadyRunning = "Yes" Then
        MsgBox ("You have Double-Clicked on this button!" _
            & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Remember, the Sales Hub is mostly Single-Click operation!" _
            & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Double-Click is only used in some Listboxes.")
        AlreadyRunning = "No"
    Else
        AlreadyRunning = "Yes"
        If SaveOnce = False Then
            ThisWorkbook.Save
            SaveOnce = True
        End If
        Your_User_Form.Show
    End If
    AlreadyRunning = "No"
End Sub
```